# Stretch database only stretches out 9999 rows

Tags: sql-server, azure-sql-database

Tried out stretch database feature in sql server 2017, but it stops sending rows to Azure after 9999 rows. Tried different tables, different databases and from different machines. Any idea why?

Answer (score 0):

Changed Azure region from Europe West to US East, and then it worked.